# Calligraphy library is not working on huawei p20 lite

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, calligraphy

i'm trying to use bebasneue font but it's not working,i have tried all methods and nothing work on phone  huawei p20 lite
this is project source code if you would like to take a farther look
https://github.com/IslamAssem/Ml3bna

Comment: did you try on other phones or emulator?

Comment: yes,and it worked